# Building a tree like structure and return in in a JSON object format

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

First I have this readModel

```
public class LevelsVisualizationReadModel: BaseReadModel
{
public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
public IEnumerable\<LevelsVisualizationReadModel\> Children { get; set; } = Enumerable.Empty\<LevelsVisualizationReadModel\>();
public List\<string\> Link { get; set; } = new();

    }
```

and this is how I load data from the database

```
var temp = await _stepRepository.FindListAsync(
                     stepPredicate,
                     selector: s => new KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>(stateNamesDictionary[s.StateId], s.ActionDestinationSteps.Select(a => stateNamesDictionary[a.DestinationStateId]).ToList())

                     );
```

and here is my function to build the tree structure:

```
private static List<LevelsVisualizationReadModel> BuildVisualizationTree(List<KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>> flatList, string parent)
{
    List<LevelsVisualizationReadModel> visualTree = new();

    foreach (var node in flatList)
    {
        if (node.Key == parent) // Check if the current node is a child of the specified parent.
        {
            var childNode = new LevelsVisualizationReadModel()
            {
                Name = node.Key,
                Children = BuildVisualizationTree(flatList, node.Key)
            };

            visualTree.Add(childNode);
        }
    }

    return visualTree;
}
```

this dose not work, its infinite and if a node is exist at higher level it should put in the link property instead of dealing with it as a child

in conclusion I want to achieve this:

```
{
  "New": {
    "children": [
      {
        "Classified": {
          "children": [
            {
              "Validate": {
                "children": [
                  {
                    "Assigned": {
                      "children": [
                        {
                          "Resolved": {},
                          "Unresolved": {}
                        },
                        {
                          "link": ["Rejected"]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "Rejected": {
                "children": [
                  {
                    "closed": {}
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```